# Having issue obtaining API key from Exact Target Appcenter

Tags: marketing-cloud

I'm having problem getting an API key from Appcenter, I can't get pass the Appcenter EULA, nothing happen when I click 'Accept'

Rog

Comment: did you try in different browsers ? can u post a screenshot or more details on your question..

Comment: I'm having a similar problem, the page https://appcenter.exacttargetapps.com/#eula keeps loading, but I don't see anything, I'm using Firefox. I also had a similar problem on the page https://appcenter.exacttargetapps.com/#register, I had to click several times on the continue button in order to make it work

Comment: After clicking several times in the Accept button, it finally worked. The registration process needs urgent improvements